# NTLM Proxy - HTTPS Alternative to CNTLM?

Tags: proxy, ntlm

I worked with a proxy at my office that I need to have applications use.  Of course its using NTLM, and that's blocking a lot of stuff from using their default/built-in proxies.

I've got Maven, Eclipse etc. using CNTLM but I'm looking for different one.  It doesn't use allow both HTTP and HTTPS.

For your various applications, what local proxy do you use to perform NTLM authentication?  I've tried looking around and can't find anything.

I'm guessing there's a hidden gem people know about... what's yours? :P

I've looked at Fiddler.. but even that doesn't seem to quite perform NTLM without pulling a few limbs.

Cheers

Comment: It's not clear that this is a programming question. What specifically do you need to accomplish? Have you tried using Fiddler?

Comment: reworded a bit for you

Comment: It is not true that CNTLM does not allow HTTPS. It works fine for HTTPS also.